# elasticsearch installation in helm fails with statefulset error

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I'm installing elasticsearch in my EKS cluster using below commands

```
helm repo add elastic https://helm.elastic.co
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/helm-charts/master/elasticsearch/values.yaml
helm install --name elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch -f ./values.yaml
```

It fails with below error

Error: template: elasticsearch/templates/statefulset.yaml:298:27: executing "elasticsearch/templates/statefulset.yaml" at <.Values.roles.master>: can't evaluate field master in type interface {}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same issue. It was due to the following [PR](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/pull/1186#discussion_r631225687) which change the role settings.

Documentation on master branch describes the new settings but it is not compatible with the last published chart version (7.13.2). Use instead values from the version you are using

```
helm repo add elastic https://helm.elastic.co
helm repo update
helm search repo elastic/elasticsearch

NAME                    CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION                                  
elastic/elasticsearch   7.13.2          7.13.2          Official Elastic helm chart for Elasticsearch
```

So use `values.yaml` from `7.13` branch

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/helm-charts/7.13/elasticsearch/values.yaml
```

Answer (score 3):

For the ones wondering about @greenmaid's answer: this error happens because of the `roles` format changed. Use something like

```
roles:
  master: "true"
  ingest: "true"
  data: "true"
```

instead of

```
roles:
  - master
  - ingest
  - data
```

Comment: thats nuts. thanks for the answer. I would never have guessed that !